# MongoDB Aggregate Query to show all objects with time between a specific time range

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to pull a list of all programs that air between 6pm and 11pm from my schedules collection. The problem is that in the match query, I am not sure how to extract the hour value from the StartUTC which is a DateTime value so that I can do the 23>x>18 comparison on all the times. Any ideas?

```
#"start": {"$gt": {"$hour": "$StartUtc"} }

print db.schedules.aggregate([
    {"$match": { "$StartUtc"" : { "$gt" : 18, "$lte" : 23 } } },
    {"$group": {"_id": "$OriginalProgramId", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])},
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [`date aggregation operators`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) and more specifically the [`$hour`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour) operator which returns the hour portion of a date.  You can get the hour in a `project` phase of the pipeline, so it's available in the subsequent phases for `match`, etc...

```js
db.schedules.aggregate([
    {"starthour": { $hour: "$StartUtc" }}, // Project other values too so it's available in the next phase of the pipeline
    {"$match": { "$starthour"" : { "$gt" : 18, "$lte" : 23 } } },
    {"$group": {"_id": "$OriginalProgramId", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
    {"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])},
])
```

**Note:**  For simplicity sake, I've only included the `starthour` field in the `project` phase.  You'll have to include other fields as well for subsequent phase of the aggregation pipeline to work.